# add_action functions the same as add_filter in wp core

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been learning WP plugin development and the tutorial that I was looking at said that Wordpress has two hooks, one being add_action and the other being add_filter. Then i searched within the core to learn more about it and i noticed that the add_action function returned an add_filter function. What is the point of using add_action if i can just use add_filter? Can someone explain this?

I found it here: /wp-includes/plugin.php

```
function add_action($tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1)
{
    return add_filter($tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args);
}
```

I had an action using admin_init to play with wordpress, i changed it to use add_filter instead and it worked without any problems. Isnt add_filter only used for string outputs while add_action uses hooks added throughout the wp core?

Comment: Well, [action has been an alias for filter](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/479fc2e2b3c08b2d3eabafaa907cc8cb2eb5b958/wp-includes/plugin.php#L399) for at least 8 years. My guess: they started with an idea they'd be different, but the implementations converged.

Comment: ic, so it wouldnt make a difference if i used add_filter or add_action right?

Comment: Bssed on the code, that appears to be true.

Comment: [This post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fliters-vs-actions-from-a-newbe) explains it really well. When you have to change the existing functions (add something to it, or change the default value), you use `add_filter`, when you want to add a completely new function, element etc. you use `add_action`. Basically with `add_filter` you always create a function that will `return` a value, whereas with `add_action` you create a function that can append a new content to the existing one (output something with `echo`).